# Dynamic import statement different results from a string vs variable path

Tags: angular, typescript, import

I'm trying to make my [static module loader](https://stackblitz.com/edit/lazy-module-wout-router) dynamic. However, import statements seem to want strings as their path.

```
import('./position/position.module').then(({ PositionModule }) => {
    console.log(PositionModule);
```

gives:

```
class PositionModule {
    constructor(componentFactoryResolver) {
        this.componentFactoryResolver = componentFactoryResolver;
    }
    resolveComponent() {
        return this.componentFactoryResol…
```

Where

```
cpts = [
    {
       import: import('./position/position.module')
    }
];
const module = await this.cpts[0].import;
```

Gives:

```
Module {__esModule: true, Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"}
```

**Why are the two import concepts returning varying results?**

Comment: There's destructuring in the first example

Comment: Dynamic import always return an promise. so in the second case, try using module.then(({ PositionModule }) => { console.log(PositionModule); }

Comment: Based on the first example I think that `const { PositionModule } = await this.cpts[0].import` resolves the issue.